# Re-arrangeable, Draggable , Sortable divs within grid

Tags: javascript, css, layout, frameworks, grid

So think if a dashboard view, which contains different divs for lets say text blocks. I want the client(user) to be able to rearrange them in a X by Y grid system.

I have an idea about how to achieve this, but I am mainly looking for a library or a specific framework that can do this. Is anyone aware of any built solution?

I dont care about css framework bootstrap etc I can use any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think React JS is well suited for this.

**Link to get started with sorting:** http://webcloud.se/sortable-list-component-react-js/

**Link to get started with dragging:** 
https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable

**UPDATE:**

This seems to be exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout

Comment: Great! now I just need to move from Angular to React, but I was gonna do that anyway! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

jQuery Sortable UI: 
https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/sortable/display-grid.html

Comment: No because I am talking about a grid system. the sortable works on a ul.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the great and quick answer from Turk. There are more options such as http://packery.metafizzy.co and http://gridster.net